# Random Variate generating strange results when using ProbabilityDistribution

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, random, distributions, histograms

**Bug introduced in 10.1 and fixed in 10.3**

---

I have created a probability distribution that follows a general normal distribution, given by:

$$
\frac{b *e^{-\left(\frac{\sqrt{(x-u )^2}}{a }\right)^{b }}}{2 a  \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{b }\right)}
$$

When I define the Probability Distribution and generate Random values for it:

```
modelDrPD =ProbabilityDistribution[modelDr/.{β->4.2,α-> 0.39, μ->0.06}, {x, -∞, ∞}] 
Histogram[RandomVariate[modelDrPD, 1000000], "FreedmanDiaconis"]
```

And I get the following histogram:

[image: Histogram]

The PDF integrates to 1, as needed... Why there is a second peak in the Histogram? It happens with many PDF I try

Thank you

Update: Here is my complete code:

```
modelDr = ( b /(2 a Gamma[1/b]) Exp[-(Sqrt[(x - u)^2]/a)^b])
modelDrPD =  ProbabilityDistribution[  modelDr /. {b -> 4.2, a -> 0.39, u -> 0.06}, {x, -Infinity,    Infinity}] 
Histogram[RandomVariate[modelDrPD, 1000000], "FreedmanDiaconis"]
```

Comment: I can't replicate the problem in 10.3 for Mac. What version are you using?

Comment: After adding in the definition `modelDr = \[Beta] Exp[-(Abs[
          x - \[Mu]]/\[Alpha])^\[Beta]]/(2 \[Alpha] Gamma[1/\[Beta]]);`, it works fine on 10.2 Windows 7.  What is your definition of `modelDr`?

Comment: With 10.1 and @JimBaldwin definition I do get the strange plot along with a bunch of underflow warnings.  Fabio you should include such warnings in your question if you got them.

Comment: It is `RandomVariate` throwing the errors. Making the parameters rational doesn't help. `RandomVariate` won't accept a `WorkingPrecision` option for some reason.

Comment: I've added the full code... I got no warnings... for some parameters values, everything goes fine...

Comment: I can't replicate the problem either [ Mac 10.3 ]. As good etiquette, it would be helpful to post the exact input that you are using:  then others can try it, and compare etc.

Comment: P.S. Your code (just posted) has invalid syntax.

Comment: I´ve reposted my code, I think now you can reproduce it... :)

Comment: I also get the underflow and weird spike in 10.1. Seems like a bug that was fixed in later versions.

Comment: interestingly, w10.1 it seems to work reliably generating single points. It is extremely slow however, estimate several days to generate a million points.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in version 10.1 that has been fixed in 10.3.  You can always try writing your own random number generator. Here is a [simple acceptance rejection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) based on generalized Gaussian distributions as discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution).

Here I use a very naive envelope, a uniform distribution over `{mu - s*sd, mu + s*sd}` where `mu` is the mean of your distribution, `sd` is the standard deviation and `s` is the number of standard deviations you would like to allow the envelope to encompass.

```
ar[a_, b_, mu_, k_, s_: 5] :=
  Block[{bag = Internal`Bag[{0.}, 1], low, high, m, c, u, f, chunk},
    (*bounds of envelope*)
    {low, high} = {mu - s #, mu + s #} &[Sqrt[a^2*Gamma[3/b]/Gamma[1/b]]];

    (*scaling factor to ensure envelope is above PDF*)
    m = (0.5*b)/(a*Gamma[b^(-1)])*(high - low);

    (*number of random variates to generate each pass optimized for 
      a minimal number of passes *)
    chunk = Ceiling[k/(high - low)*m];

    (*add accepted variates to a bag until enough have been collected*)
    While[Internal`BagLength[bag] < k,
      c = RandomReal[{low, high}, chunk];
      u = RandomReal[{0., 1.}, chunk];
      f = b/(2*a*E^((a^(-1))^b*Abs[c - mu]^b)*Gamma[b^(-1)]);
      Internal`StuffBag[bag, Pick[c, UnitStep[f/(m/(high - low) ) - u], 1], 1];
    ];

    (*return only the first k random variates*)
    Internal`BagPart[bag, All][[1 ;; k]]
  ]
```

This could probably be made faster by compilation or by choosing a better envelope but it is a good start and doesn't issue underflow messages.

```
modelDr = (b/(2 a Gamma[1/b]) Exp[-(Sqrt[(x - u)^2]/a)^b]);
modelDrPD = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[
   modelDr /. {b -> 4.2, a -> 0.39, u -> 0.06}, {x, -Infinity, 
    Infinity}];

Show[Histogram[ar[.39, 4.2, .06, 1000000], "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"],
  Plot[PDF[modelDrPD, x], {x, -1, 1}]]
```

[image]